# Как убрать ненужные локали, чтобы они не попадали в финальную сборку проекта? Moment.js, Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, momentjs

Использую библиотеку `Moment.js` в `React`-приложении. При сборке вебпаком видно что в финальный бандл попадают все языки из библиотеки, хотя в проекте используется только русский. Как сделать чтобы остальные языки не попадали в сборку?

Подключаю библиотеку так `import * as moment from 'moment'`

Использую, например, так: `const deadline = moment(state.deadline).format(DD_MM_YYYY)`

Проверяю оптимизированный production бандл
[image: 669 килобайт]

Comment: добавь в вопрос, как подключаешь библиотеку  и пример как используешь.

Comment: проверяешь ли ты оптимизированный production бандл или dev версию?

Comment: дополнил вопрос по замечаниям

Comment: [To strip unnecessary locales and bundle only the used ones, add moment-locales-webpack-plugin](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/00-use-it/08-webpack/)

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало)

Answer (score 1):

Grundy дал ответ. Чтобы удалить ненужные локали, необходимо воспользоваться
[moment-locales-webpack-plugin](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/00-use-it/08-webpack/)